# Dynamically adding a class to a div in a .erb with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this div

```
<div class='notice'>
```

And I want the result to be

```
<div class="notice error">
```

And Is there a way to add a class in my erb? I tried

```
<div class="notice #{new_class}">
```

But that doesn't escape into ruby code when it renders...

and ideas?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's with `<%=` `%>`

```
<div class="notice <%= new_class %>">
```

Answer (score 15):

I believe

```
<div class="notice <%= h new_class -%>">
```

works, albeit a little ugly. You could also do the prettier, but more longwinded

```
<%= content_tag(:div, "Your content here", :class => "notice #{new_class}") %>
```